# Visualisation of a relationship between families of stochastic processes

Tags: self-study, references, stochastic-processes

I am looking for a diagram of stochastic processes like the [Univariate Distribution Relationship Chart](http://www.math.wm.edu/%7Eleemis/chart/UDR/UDR.html)

Maybe someone know a visualisation of a relationship between families of stochastic processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Image of stochastic processes relationships]

is associated with the reference (Sciencedirect) [Time Stochastic Process](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/time-stochastic-process).  A link for the source document is here: [Handbook of Statistics: Chapter 5 - Studying Complexity and Risk Through Stochastic Population Dynamics: Persistence, Resonance, and Extinction in Ecosystems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169716118300944).  [An ungated link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330251417_Studying_Complexity_and_Risk_Through_Stochastic_Population_Dynamics_Persistence_Resonance_and_Extinction_in_Ecosystems)

Comment: Try to find the original text of the manuscript. Why are a diffusion and OU-process separated?